# Apache Camel Message Acknowledgement with seda endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, redhat, jbossfuse

I am trying to write a route that forwards the message to a seda endpoint like this

```
from(jms:queue:testQueue)
.process(/** do something ** /)
.inOnly(seda:test?waitForTaskCompletion=Never)
.end();
```

There is another route that consumes from seda endpoint:

```
from(seda:test)
.process(/** do something **)
.end();
```

JMS Acknowledgement mode for the JMS connection factory is CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and I have configured the project using spring-boot. As per the configuration as soon as the first camel route ends it should commit the transaction and send the acknowledgement to message broker.

But, the behaviour is message acknowledgement happens only after the second route completes. What could I configure in the first route to acknowledge message immediately? AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE is not an option I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to insert a wiretap which call your seda route ?